# Why is firefox developer console referring to script.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, firefox, console

Firefox developer web console is suddenly showing "mutation events are deprecated..." on a line within script.js but I'm not using such a script.

When I click to view the line in question the following code is highlighted:

```
e=true;break}if(!e)return false;if(""!=t){e=false;for(k=0;k<f.length;++k)if(t==f[k]){e=true;break}if(!e)return false;if(""!=u&&c){e=false;for(k=0;k<s.length;++k)if(u==s[k]){e=true;break}if(!e)return false}}else if(!b)return false;return true}if(isMozillaFirefox||isGoogleChrome||isAppleSafari){doc.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",j,false);doc.addEventListener("DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument",h,false)}if(isInternetExplorer)if(getBrowserVersion()>=9){doc.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",j,false);doc.addEventListener("DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument",
```

Comment: Any addons installed? If so, have you tried disabling them?

Comment: I disabled all of my addons and the error has disappeared. I'll have to enable them one by one to see which is the faulty addon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled all addons and one-by-one enabled them again testing the web console. In case this helps someone else with the same error, the addon that causes the problem for me is called: **DivX Plus Web Player HTML5 `<video>` 2.1.2.145**